# In my enemy is my friend

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> In my enemy is my friend
>   In my friend is my enemy
>   I exist because he does
>   But he exists from where I don't
>   Round and round we go again
>   Each placed in the other's domain
>   But most places we are seen
>   We are seen as part of the same dream
>   Where 1 is 2 and in that 2 are 2 more
>   My purpose is to show
>   You can't have one without the other, forever more!

What am I?

Comment: Makes me think of light and darkness

Comment: I can't understand this line `Where 1 is 2 and in that 2 are 2 more` here `2` is _what?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are

> yin and yang: [image: yin yang symbol]

*In my enemy is my friend

In my friend is my enemy*

> Seemingly contrary forces can be interlinked, such as good and bad or light and dark.

*I exist because he does

But he exists from where I don't*

> The concept of *bad* can only exist if *good* does, and vice-versa, and where there is not *bad*, there can be *good*. (Same applies to other apparently opposite forces.)

*Round and round we go again

Each placed in the other's domain*

> As on the traditional symbol, the swirls follow each other.

*But most places we are seen

We are seen as part of the same dream*

> Sometimes there's a fine line between the two, or none at all.

*Where 1 is 2 and in that 2 are 2 more*

> The one symbol has two swirly shapes in, each containing one small circle.

*My purpose is to show

You can't have one without the other, forever more!*

> The symbol represents the concept of [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang), which could be called *timeless*.

Comment: I'd like to suggest editing the fifth explanation, since that line of riddle is actually originated from a sentence of [I Ching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiji_(philosophy)) which is well known by Chinese people.

Comment: Please do @ShaneHsu, I think you can click on *edit* underneath. (I'm not sure how to explain better.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Fire and water

In my enemy is my friend
In my friend is my enemy

> In fire and water is oxygen.

I exist because he does
But he exists from where I don't

> They both exist because of oxygen and water exists in the sea where fire can't.

Round and round we go again
Each placed in the other's domain

> Water puts out fire, but fire evaporates water.

But most places we are seen
We are seen as part of the same dream

> They are both part of the 4 elements - water, air, fire and earth.

Where 1 is 2 and in that 2 are 2 more
My purpose is to show

> Not sure, but fire is to show light. @yitzih suggested H<sub>2</sub>0?

You can't have one without the other, forever more!

> You can't have water and fire without oxygen.

Comment: You got the last two wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @Beastly Gerbil's answer:

Where 1 is 2 and in that 2 are 2 more:

> In Water(H2O) there are 2 elements (Hydrogen and Oxygen) and the are 2 of the Hydrogen atom.